# Java code not able to read file from HDFS completely

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am reading a file from HDFS. I am using below code to achieve this.

```
public class ClassMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    Path inFile = new Path(args[1]);
    Path outFile = new Path(args[2]);
    FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(inFile);
    FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(outFile);
    byte buffer[] = new byte[4096];
    try{
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) 
    {
    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
    System.out.println("ERROR*****************"+e);
    }   
    finally
    {
    in.close();
    out.close();
    }
```

It is not able to read my file from HDFS completely. The size of the sample file is 1004.9 K. I tried increasing the value as high as

```
byte buffer[] = new byte[12000000];
```

But it is still not able to read the file completely.

Is there any alternate way to do this? This is just a small sample size of 1MB in HDFS. Files would be as large as 3 to 4 GB. 
Is there any way to use something like:  `long buffer[] = new long[12000000];` so that it can accomodate larger size in buffer.

Comment: Do you really need to download the whole file? If so, why did you put it in HDFS? Can you use Spark, for example, to operate over parts of the file?

Answer (score 1):

```
(bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0
```

The condition is wrong, it is perfectly possible for a stream to read 0 bytes over the network. Only -1 determines the end of the stream.

So that should fix the problem for you:

```
while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
```

As you can imagine, there are already libraries for that, `commons-io` for example comes with a method called `copy` that copies one stream to another.

Simple example in three lines:

```
try(FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(inFile)){
    try(FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(outFile)){
       IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    }
}
```

Comment: while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1)  did not help . Infact it slowed down performance on a smaller sized file as well. And it did not solve the issue for large file.

Comment: The second option also did the same for small and large files

Comment: I am trying to increase the value for new byte[] and keeping the condition as in.read(buffer) != -1. For smaller values, it read small part in the buffer and I increased it further. It does not have effect after 517888. It does not change the part read by buffer beyond this point. I dont understand what is the problem with my code.

Comment: Actually, I am sending the input file as a parameter to one method. And I am converting the byte buffer[] = new byte[517888] to string using String str= new String(buffer) and passing str to that method as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Found this code which works for me. It can read file of larger size as well.

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    Path inFile = new Path(args[1]);
    Path outFile = new Path(args[2]);

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(inFile)));
    String line;
    line=br.readLine();

    String concatAllLines = line;
    while (line != null){
            //System.out.println("reading lines");
            line=br.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            if(line != null)
                concatAllLines += line;
    }

    System.out.println(concatAllLines);
}
```